# Build react-native run-android on windows

Tags: react-native

I try build react-native run-android on windows this bug appear[image]

then i do follow the answer on this github issue try Command `chmod 755 android/gradlew` on root folder but `chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` i think this answer for linux . Some body help me . Thanks for reading my question

Comment: have you try follow this [tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) for getting started with ReactNative on Window ? i think your problem because your miss one way on the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

The error states that you neither have any android device connected nor do you have emulator running. Follow [this guide](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.25/docs/getting-started.html) for android setup.

If you already have android setup and running emulator, try restarting it and run following commands:

Try running following commands:

1. `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
2. `cd .. && react-native run-android`

Comment: In terminal, from your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

From your question seems like you are not started your emulator or device connected.

Follow this steps:-

1.Open your CMD/Terminal from your system

2. write this command cd "YOUR PATH TO ANDROID SDK"

   for example, mine looks like::-

cd /Users/trainee02/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

and then hit enter.

3.after enter in directory write this command

export PATH="/Users/YOUR SYSTEM USER NAME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH

above command is for running android from MAC pc.

then last command is

4.adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

hit enter

or you can check reference that given in official site

[Running On Device React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You must update Tools sdk revision 23.0.1 on Android Studio